# (javascript) There seem to be two things wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, debugging, callback, this

Do I need to execute a bind(this) somewhere and the console log placement seems to be off?

```js
var company = {
  employees: [{
      name: "doug"
    },
    {
      name: "AJ"
    }
  ],
  getName: function(employee) {
    return employee.name
  },
  getNames: function() {
    return this.employees.map(this.getName)
  },
  delayedGetNames: function() {
    setTimeout(this.getNames, 500)
  }
}

console.log(company.delayedGetNames());
```

Comment: `company.delayedGetNames` doesn't return anything. It just runs a `setTimeout`. You might want to look into promises or async/await functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(this.getNames.bind(this), 500)
                         ^
                         |
                         +----< HERE
```

```js
var company = {
  employees: [{
      name: "doug"
    },
    {
      name: "AJ"
    }
  ],
  getName: function(employee) {
    return employee.name
  },
  getNames: function() {
    return this.employees.map(this.getName)
  },
  delayedGetNames: function() {
    var fn = function() {
      var names = this.getNames();
      console.log(names);
    };
    
    setTimeout(fn.bind(this), 500);
  }
}

company.delayedGetNames();
```

Comment: This code snippet just returns 'called from map' twice?

Comment: @Jimmy yes, because `employees` has two objects!

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this function correctly but would the purpose not be to return the 2 names once it is evaluated?

Comment: It returns an array with two names, but your code doesn't print anaything.  See the answer updated.